# Getting the color of a pixel in Java

Tags: java

I have a chessboard that colors specific squares blue (`Color.BLUE`), and I want to have the program know when the user clicks on blue squares. I know the X and Y coordinates of the click, but how do I do this? Others create an image and then use `.getRGB()`, but is there another way?

Comment: The answer will depend on "how" the board is generated

Comment: Please explain downvotes. They are not very helpful otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: Not the down voter, but the question is vague and shows little effort to solve the problem. For example, we have absolutely no idea about the frame work you are using or how the board is generated...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am fully aware of the need to show effort, but in this case, I could not because the program is very long and I thought, a bit unnecessary in this case. (I did do some research, though, which is how I learned about .getRGB().) However, thank you for the explanation, and I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be trying to "get the color of a pixel".  The logic that handles the chessboard knows what the board layout is and what pixels it's coloring, so it should be retaining enough of this information so that it can tell what square is being clicked on.  The OOP way to do this is: define a class `Chessboard` whose purpose is to represent a chessboard drawn in the window (or Swing component, or whatever).  There should be a method to draw the chessboard; that method will keep track of the range of pixels are used to draw each square.  (Since each square will probably have the same height and width, you shouldn't actually need to keep an array of pixel coordinates; keeping just the coordinate of the upper left corner of the chessboard will be enough, and you'll add something like `width * columnNumber` or `height * rowNumber` to get the coordinate of each square.)  The data about where the squares are drawn will be in member fields in the `Chessboard`.  Then you can add a method that asks the `Chessboard` "what square contains the pixel at coordinates X and Y?".  I've left out a lot of details, but I think that's the best general approach for this problem.

Comment: To clarify - is "getting the color of a pixel" just not possible at all, or just bad logic? (I actually had all the beginning things you mentioned, but thought if this was possible, it would certainly be quite helpful.)

Comment: @user3141193 "Getting the color of a pixel" is certainly possible if you explain *where the hell the pixel is*. Is it in an array? In a `java.awt.BufferedImage`? On a Swing component? On an AWT component? On a JavaFX component? On an Android component? In some other program on the screen? On a texture loaded into the GPU? In a picture file on disk? On a web page? That matters and you didn't explain it at all. But yes it's an awful thing to want to do in this case.

Comment: @Boann I am sorry I did not explain that - I am not the greatest programmer there is, and I did not know that that would matter. I simply made a chessboard with .drawRect(), .fillRect(), etc. in the paint method of my class, which extends Panel. I understand that getting the color of a pixel is a bad thing to do, but _why_ is my question.

Comment: @user3141193 Yes, it's possible, and I once wrote a practice program that used one of the text components to display some text, then used logic that accessed the pixels directly to display a mirror image of the text.  It's not trivial, though; if I recall, I had to set up some additional buffers in which to draw the text.  You can't quite display it in the same way you would if you didn't need pixel access.  (I think MadProgrammer helped me figure this out.)   Unfortunately I haven't found the program yet.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is another and a better way!
As you already have `x` and `y` coordinates of **click**, you can now check where these coordinates fall in the chess board grid and you can know exactly which box was clicked.

As chessboards squares are rendered at specific coordinates by you, i guess so, you can perform an algorithm to compare `x` and `y` coordinates against those of **square** and you will have the **position**.

If this don't help let me know with more specifics, I may be able to help you then.

Answer (score 3):

I would store an array of `Rectangle`s and find out which one contains the point when clicked.

[image: Chessboard Image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChessBoard extends JPanel {

    public static final int SIZE = 400;
    public static final int COUNT = 8;
    public static final int TILE_SIZE = SIZE / COUNT;
    public static final Color RED = Color.RED;
    public static final Color BLUE = Color.BLUE;

    public static Tile[][] tiles;

    static {
        ChessBoard c = new ChessBoard();

        tiles = new Tile[COUNT][COUNT];

        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COUNT; j++) {
                tiles[i][j] = c.new Tile(i * TILE_SIZE, j * TILE_SIZE,
                        TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        ChessBoard c = new ChessBoard();

        f.setTitle("Chessboard Tile Click");
        f.setContentPane(c);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public ChessBoard() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE));

        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                Point p = e.getPoint();

                for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < COUNT; j++) {
                        Rectangle tile = tiles[i][j];

                        if (tile.contains(p)) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                    String.format("Clicked Tile: %s", tile));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        boolean flip = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COUNT; j++) {
                Rectangle tile = tiles[i][j];

                g.setColor((flip = !flip) ? BLUE : RED);
                g.fillRect(tile.x, tile.y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);

                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.drawString(tile.toString(), tile.x + (TILE_SIZE / 2) - 8,
                        tile.y + (TILE_SIZE / 2) + 6);
            }
            flip = !flip;
        }
    }

    private class Tile extends Rectangle {
        public Tile(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            super(x, y, width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%c%d", 'A' + x / TILE_SIZE, COUNT - y
                    / TILE_SIZE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though it does not affect the program execution, it does affect the time. I have changed SIZE to COUNT in all loops. Oops...

Answer (score 1):

Trying to use the color of the pixel for this is perverse... I'm horrified. No, do this:

1. Use the mouse x and y to determine which square was clicked.
2. Using the same rule you used to determine the "specific" squares to color blue: determine the nature of the clicked square and take the appropriate action.